Proving completeness of a space of bounded functions
The problem statement reads:
Problem:
Let $ O $ be a non-empty subset with $ \omega_0 \in O $, and define
$$ 
X(O) = \left\{ f: O \to \mathbb{R} \mid f \in B(O), f(\omega_0) = 0 \right\}, 
$$
where $ B(O) $ denotes the space of bounded functions on $ O $. Show that $ (X(O), \|\cdot\|_\infty) $ is a Banach space.
My attempt at a solution:
To show that $ (X(O), \|\cdot\|_\infty) $ is a Banach space, we need to prove two things:

$ X(O) $ is a normed vector space under the infinity norm $ \|\cdot\|_\infty $.
$ X(O) $ is complete, meaning every Cauchy sequence in $ X(O) $ converges to an element within $ X(O) $.

Step 1: Verify $ X(O) $ is a Normed Vector Space
The infinity norm on $ X(O) $ is defined by:
$$
\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in O} |f(x)|.
$$
We need to verify that this norm satisfies the properties of a norm:

Non-negativity: For all $ f \in X(O) $, $ \|f\|_\infty \geq 0 $ and $ \|f\|_\infty = 0 $ if and only if $ f = 0 $.
Scalar multiplication: For any $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ f \in X(O) $, $ \|\alpha f\|_\infty = |\alpha| \|f\|_\infty $.
Triangle inequality: For all $ f, g \in X(O) $, $ \|f + g\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty + \|g\|_\infty $.

Since $ f(\omega_0) = 0 $ for all $ f \in X(O) $, $ X(O) $ is a subspace of the space of bounded functions $ B(0) $, and the norm properties are preserved. Therefore, $ X(O) $ is a normed vector space.
Step 2: Prove Completeness of $ X(O) $
We now need to show that $ X(O) $ is complete. Let $ (f_n) $ be a Cauchy sequence in $ X(O) $. By the definition of a Cauchy sequence, for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists an $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $ m, n \geq N $,
$$
\|f_n - f_m\|_\infty < \epsilon.
$$
Since $ \|f_n - f_m\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in O} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| $, it follows that $ (f_n(x)) $ is a Cauchy sequence in $ \mathbb{R} $ for each $ x \in O $. The real numbers are complete, so $ (f_n(x)) $ converges to some limit $ f(x) \in \mathbb{R} $ for each $ x \in O $.
Define $ f: O \to \mathbb{R} $ by
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x).
$$
Since each $ f_n \in B(0) $ and the limit of a bounded sequence is bounded, $ f $ is also bounded. Moreover, since $ f_n(\omega_0) = 0 $ for all $ n $, we have
$$
f(\omega_0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(\omega_0) = 0.
$$
Thus, $ f \in X(O) $.
Step 3: Show Convergence in the Infinity Norm
To conclude that $ f_n \to f $ in the norm $ \|\cdot\|_\infty $, we need to verify that $ \|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty $. Since $ (f_n) $ is Cauchy, given $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $ m, n \geq N $, $ \|f_n - f_m\|_\infty < \epsilon/2 $. Fix $ n \geq N $, and let $ m \to \infty $. We have
$$
\|f_n - f\|_\infty = \lim_{m \to \infty} \|f_n - f_m\|_\infty \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.
$$
Thus, $ \|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0 $, which shows that $ f_n \to f $ in $ X(O) $.
Since every Cauchy sequence in $ X(O) $ converges to a limit in $ X(O) $, the space is complete. Therefore, $ (X(O), \|\cdot\|_\infty) $ is a Banach space.
Is this proof correct and complete or any there any mistakes? Are there any alternate methods to proof this? Also, if anyone could share any  sources to understand this better that would be helpful. Thank you for your help.

Prove that $B(O)$ is complete with respect to $|\cdot|_\infty$ norm. The linear functional $\varphi(f)=f(\omega_0)$ is continuous (bounded). Thus $\ker \varphi =X(O)$ is a closed subspace of the complete space $B(O).$  Hence it is complete.
